# T-SQL: Adding namespaces to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, namespaces

I am creating T-SQL code to retrieve information in XML form.

The below shows the current output from the T-SQL code:

```
<ReportingGroup>
  <AccountReport>
    <AccountNumber>12312334</AccountNumber>
    <AccountClosed>false</AccountClosed>
    <AccountHolder>
      <Individual>
        <ResCountryCode>USA</ResCountryCode>
        <TIN>23423545</TIN>
        <Name>
          <FirstName>John</FirstName>
          <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        </Name>
        <Address>
          <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
          <AddressFix>
            <Street>112323 ljlkjlkyoid</Street>
            <BuildingIdentifier>NULL</BuildingIdentifier>
            <PostCode>NULL</PostCode>
            <City>USA</City>
          </AddressFix>
          <AddressFree>NULL</AddressFree>
        </Address>
        <BirthInfo />
      </Individual>
    </AccountHolder>
    <FINAL_BALANCE_USD></FINAL_BALANCE_USD>
    <NAME_TEXT>John Doe</NAME_TEXT>
    <NAME_ADDR_TEXT>87 ljhadliwhdlahd</NAME_ADDR_TEXT>
    <NAME_CITY>U.S.A.</NAME_CITY>
  </AccountReport>
</ReportingGroup>
```

How can i modify the T-SQL to add the ftc: and sfc: in the xml tags like the output below?

```
SELECT
AccountNumber
, AccountClosed
, (
    SELECT --level 2
    ResCountryCode
    , TIN
    , (
        SELECT --level 3
        FirstName
        LastName
        for xml path('Name'), TYPE

       )
     , (
        SELECT --level 3
        CountryCode
        ,(
            SELECT --LEVEL 4
            Street
            , BuildingIdentifier
            , PostCode
            , City
            for xml path('AddressFix'), TYPE
        )
        , AddressFree
        for xml path('Address'), TYPE
       )

     , (
        SELECT --level 3
        BirthDate
        for xml path('BirthInfo'), TYPE
        )
    for xml path('Individual'),  root('AccountHolder'), TYPE
  )
From test_table
for xml path('AccountReport'), root('ReportingGroup')
```

OUTPUT:

```
 <ftc:ReportingGroup>
      <ftc:AccountReport>
        <ftc:AccountNumber>12312334</ftc:AccountNumber>
        <ftc:AccountClosed>false</ftc:AccountClosed>
        <ftc:AccountHolder>
          <ftc:Individual>
            <sfa:ResCountryCode>USA</sfa:ResCountryCode>
            <sfa:TIN>23423545</sfa:TIN>
            <sfa:Name>
              <sfa:FirstName>John</sfa:FirstName>
              <sfa:LastName>Doe</sfa:LastName>
            </sfa:Name>
            <sfa:Address>
              <sfa:CountryCode>USA</sfa:CountryCode>
              <sfa:AddressFix>
                <sfa:Street>112323 ljlkjlkyoid</sfa:Street>
                <sfa:BuildingIdentifier>NULL</sfa:BuildingIdentifier>
                <sfa:PostCode>NULL</sfa:PostCode>
                <sfa:City>USA</sfa:City>
              </sfa:AddressFix>
              <sfa:AddressFree>NULL</sfa:AddressFree>
            </sfa:Address>
          </ftc:Individual>
        </ftc:AccountHolder>
        <ftc:FINAL_BALANCE_USD></ftc:FINAL_BALANCE_USD>
        <ftc:NAME_TEXT>John Doe</ftc:NAME_TEXT>
        <ftc:NAME_ADDR_TEXT>87 ljhadliwhdlahd</ftc:NAME_ADDR_TEXT>
        <ftc:NAME_CITY>U.S.A.</ftc:NAME_CITY>
      </ftc:AccountReport>
    </ftc:ReportingGroup>
```

Comment: Just as a hint: Your output is not valid... If you want to use the namespace prefixes, these namespaces must be declared...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Note that I have not tested the posted answers as yet and I will today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the nested `SELECT`s if there is no `1:n` data. Try it like this

**mockup shortened to some exemplary fields**

```
DECLARE @account TABLE(AccountNumber INT,AccountClosed BIT);
DECLARE @holder TABLE(AccountNumber INT,FirstName VARCHAR(100),LastName VARCHAR(100),Street VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @account VALUES(123,0);
INSERT INTO @holder VALUES(123,'Jim','Baker','Bakerstreet 1');

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('SomeFtcUri' AS ftc
                  ,'SomeSfaUri' AS sfa)
SELECT a.AccountNumber AS [ftc:AccountNumber]
      ,a.AccountClosed AS [ftc:AccountClosed]
      ,h.FirstName AS [sfa:AccountHolder/sfa:Individual/sfa:Name/sfa:FirstName]
      ,h.LastName AS [sfa:AccountHolder/sfa:Individual/sfa:Name/sfa:LastName]
      ,h.Street AS [sfa:AccountHolder/sfa:Individual/sfa:Address/sfa:AddressFix/sfa:Street]
FROM @account AS a
INNER JOIN @holder AS h ON a.AccountNumber=h.AccountNumber
FOR XML PATH('ftc:AccountReport'),ROOT('ftc:ReportingGroup');
```

The result

```
<ftc:ReportingGroup xmlns:sfa="SomeSfaUri" xmlns:ftc="SomeFtcUri">
  <ftc:AccountReport>
    <ftc:AccountNumber>123</ftc:AccountNumber>
    <ftc:AccountClosed>0</ftc:AccountClosed>
    <sfa:AccountHolder>
      <sfa:Individual>
        <sfa:Name>
          <sfa:FirstName>Jim</sfa:FirstName>
          <sfa:LastName>Baker</sfa:LastName>
        </sfa:Name>
        <sfa:Address>
          <sfa:AddressFix>
            <sfa:Street>Bakerstreet 1</sfa:Street>
          </sfa:AddressFix>
        </sfa:Address>
      </sfa:Individual>
    </sfa:AccountHolder>
  </ftc:AccountReport>
</ftc:ReportingGroup>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Another question how do i put the attribute currCode="USD" like: <ftc:AccountBalance currCode="USD">200</ftc:AccountBalance> ?

Comment: @Rocklee Just add the attribute with a `@` char like `'USD' AS ftc:AccountBalance/@currCode`. This must placed **before** the element itself...

Answer (score 0):

you may need to add the namespaces like this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as ftc)  
SELECT
AccountNumber
, AccountClosed
, (
    SELECT --level 2
    ResCountryCode
    , TIN
    , (
        SELECT --level 3
        FirstName
        LastName
        for xml path('Name'), TYPE

       )
     , (
        SELECT --level 3
        CountryCode
        ,(
            SELECT --LEVEL 4
            Street
            , BuildingIdentifier
            , PostCode
            , City
            for xml path('AddressFix'), TYPE
        )
        , AddressFree
        for xml path('Address'), TYPE
       )

     , (
        SELECT --level 3
        BirthDate
        for xml path('BirthInfo'), TYPE
        )
    for xml path('Individual'),  root('AccountHolder'), TYPE
  )
From test_table
for xml path('AccountReport'), root('ReportingGroup')
```

Comment: Hi, i tried that at first but it only places ftc: around the main outer tags like: <ReportingGroup xmlns:ftc="uri"> . I want to add them like my output example i showed above.

Comment: ok, because you have nested emails. You can then add the namespaces before each select ... for xml

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question at all. Adding a namespace declaration will not place the wanted prefixes at the right place...